# Adding Custom Root Mean Square Error Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have the following code in Keras:

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
     return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

However, instead of taking the mean, I want to sum and then divide by a number different from the total number of terms (slightly different from the mean). In other words, something like this:

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
     return K.sqrt(K.divide(K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true)), divideByValue))
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a Keras.backend divide function. How can I do this? 
Also are y_true & y_pred numpy arrays, or are they arrays of a different type?

Comment: Just use the normal `/` operator like so:
`return K.sqrt((K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true))/ divideByValue))`

Comment: Ohh ic. Thanks. Also, are y_pred and y_true numpy arrays? I need to find the number of zeros in each array

Comment: You cannot treat them as numpy arrays, no. However, you'd probably have better luck if you use `tf.keras` instead of `keras` in terms of using tf tensors in losses and such. Did you try using just tf operations? I don't really know whether that would work.

Comment: If you can, then you could do `num_zeros=tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.not_equal(y_pred,0),tf.ones_like(y_pred),tf.zeros_like(y_pred)))`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The easiest of which is probably just using the `/` operator:

```
K.sqrt((K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true))/ divideByValue))
```